# How do I add floating IPs to my ansible Openstack deployment?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

So, I successfully deployed openstack with two interfaces. One having an external IP (Which I use to connect to my openstack deployment) and another dummy interface with only an internal network IP (No connection to the net).

I have bought more IPs and NICs, How do I attach these to my openstack deployment so that users can use them to connect remotely to their instances?

Comment: https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/user-guide/cli-manage-ip-addresses.html read the  Manual? :-)

Comment: @djdomi maybe read the question details next time :). I am the administrator of openstack itself, not client.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, floating IPs are not configured via openstack-ansible. You add them after the cluster is up and running, either via the openstack client directly (see https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/command-objects/floating-ip-port-forwarding.html), or a provider/intermediary like Terraform (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/networking_floatingip_v2).